# Reverse Range in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a way to work with reverse ranges in Swift?

For example:

```
for i in 5...1 {
  // do something
}
```

is an infinite loop.

In newer versions of Swift that code compiles, but at runtime gives the error:

> Fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound

I know I can use `1..5` instead, calculate `j = 6 - i` and use `j` as my index. I was just wondering if there was anything more legible?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42467712/1966109) for a similar question that gives up to 8 ways to solve your problem with Swift 3.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

**Update For latest Swift 3 (still works in Swift 4)**

You can use the `reversed()` method on a range

```
for i in (1...5).reversed() { print(i) } // 5 4 3 2 1
```

Or `stride(from:through:by:)` method

```
for i in stride(from:5,through:1,by:-1) { print(i) } // 5 4 3 2 1
```

`stride(from:to:by:)` is similar but excludes the last value

```
for i in stride(from:5,to:0,by:-1) { print(i) } // 5 4 3 2 1
```

**Update For latest Swift 2**

First of all, protocol extensions change how `reverse` is used:

`for i in (1...5).reverse() { print(i) } // 5 4 3 2 1`

Stride has been reworked in Xcode 7 Beta 6. The new usage is:

```
for i in 0.stride(to: -8, by: -2) { print(i) } // 0 -2 -4 -6
for i in 0.stride(through: -8, by: -2) { print(i) } // 0 -2 -4 -6 -8
```

It also works for `Doubles`:

```
for i in 0.5.stride(to:-0.1, by: -0.1) { print(i) }
```

Be wary of floating point compares here for the bounds.

**Earlier edit for Swift 1.2**: As of Xcode 6 Beta 4, **by** and **ReverseRange** don't exist anymore :[

If you are just looking to reverse a range, the **reverse** function is all you need:

```
for i in reverse(1...5) { println(i) } // prints 5,4,3,2,1
```

As posted by **0x7fffffff** there is a new **stride** construct which can be used to iterate and increment by arbitrary integers. Apple also stated that floating point support is coming.

Sourced from his answer:

```
for x in stride(from: 0, through: -8, by: -2) {
    println(x) // 0, -2, -4, -6, -8
}

for x in stride(from: 6, to: -2, by: -4) {
    println(x) // 6, 2
}
```

Comment: FYI Stride has changed since beta 6

Comment: it should be `(1...5).reverse()` (as a function call), please update your answer. (Since it's only two characters, I couldn't edit your post.)

Comment: In Swift 3.0-PREVIEW-4 (and possibly earlier), it should be `(1...5).reversed()`. Also, the example for `.stride()` doesn't work, and needs the free function `stride(from:to:by:)` instead.

Comment: looks like the `stride` code for swift 3 is slightly incorrect. to include the number 1, you would need to use `through` opposed to `to` like this: `for i in stride(from:5,through:1,by:-1) { print(i) }`

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `reversed` has a complexity of O(1) because it merely wraps the original collection and doesn't require an iteration to build it.

Answer (score 26):

There's something troubling about the asymmetry of this:

```
for i in (1..<5).reverse()
```

...as opposed to this:

```
for i in 1..<5 {
```

It means that every time I want to do a reverse range, I have to remember to put the parentheses, plus I have to write that `.reverse()` on the end, sticking out like a sore thumb. This is really ugly in comparison to C-style for loops, which are symmetrical counting up and counting down. So I tended to use C-style for loops instead. But in Swift 2.2, C-style for loops are going away! So I've had to scurry around replacing all my decrementing C-style for loops with this ugly `.reverse()` construct — wondering all the while, why on earth isn't there a reverse-range operator?

But wait! This is Swift — we're allowed to define our own operators!! Here we go:

```
infix operator >>> {
    associativity none
    precedence 135
}

func >>> <Pos : ForwardIndexType where Pos : Comparable>(end:Pos, start:Pos)
    -> ReverseRandomAccessCollection<(Range<Pos>)> {
        return (start..<end).reverse()
}
```

So now I'm allowed to say:

```
for i in 5>>>1 {print(i)} // 4, 3, 2, 1
```

This covers just the most common case that occurs in my code, but it *is* far and away the most common case, so it's all I need at present.

I had a kind of internal crisis coming up with the operator. I would have liked to use `>..`, as being the reverse of `..<`, but that's not legal: you can't use a dot after a non-dot, it appears. I considered `..>` but decided it was too hard to distinguish from `..<`. The nice thing about `>>>` is that it screams at you: "*down* to!" (Of course you're free to come up with another operator. But my advice is: for super symmetry, define `<<<` to do what `..<` does, and now you've got `<<<` and `>>>` which are symmetrical and easy to type.)

---

#### Swift 3 version (Xcode 8 seed 6):

```
infix operator >>> : RangeFormationPrecedence
func >>><Bound>(maximum: Bound, minimum: Bound) ->
    ReversedRandomAccessCollection<CountableRange<Bound>> 
    where Bound : Comparable, Bound.Stride : Integer {
        return (minimum..<maximum).reversed()
}
```

#### Swift 4 version (Xcode 9 beta 3):

```
infix operator >>> : RangeFormationPrecedence
func >>><Bound>(maximum: Bound, minimum: Bound)
    -> ReversedRandomAccessCollection<CountableRange<Bound>>
    where Bound : Comparable & Strideable { 
        return (minimum..<maximum).reversed()
}
```

#### Swift 4.2 version (Xcode 10 beta 1):

```
infix operator >>> : RangeFormationPrecedence
func >>><Bound>(maximum: Bound, minimum: Bound)
    -> ReversedRandomAccessCollection<Range<Bound>>
    where Bound : Strideable { 
        return (minimum..<maximum).reversed()
}
```

#### Swift 5 version (Xcode 10.2.1):

```
infix operator >>> : RangeFormationPrecedence
func >>><Bound>(maximum: Bound, minimum: Bound)
    -> ReversedCollection<Range<Bound>>
    where Bound : Strideable {
        return (minimum..<maximum).reversed()
}
```

Comment: Wow, the `>>>` operator is really cool! I hope Swift designers pay attention to things like that, because sticking `reverse()` on the end of parenthesized expressions does feel weird. There's no reason they couldn't deal with `5>..0` ranges automatically, because `ForwardIndexType` protocol provides a perfectly reasonable `distanceTo()` operator that can be used to figure out if the stride should be positive or negative.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight - This came up for me because in one of my apps I had a _lot_ of C for loops (in Objective-C) that migrated to Swift C-style for loops and now had to be converted because C-style for loops are going away. This was simply terrifying, because these loops represented the core of my app's logic, and rewriting everything risked breakage. Thus I wanted a notation that would make the correspondence with the (commented-out) C-style notation as clear as possible.

Comment: @matt covers the `>>>` operator in his book [iOS 14 Programming Fundamentals with Swift](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ios-14-programming/9781492092087/), Chapter 5, Operators section, p. 302 in my copy (2020-09-23 release). Another fun operator by @matt is `^^` for exponentiation. To quote from the beginning of the Operators section: "Swift operators such as + and > are not magically baked into the language. They are, in fact, functions; they are explicitly declared and implemented just like any other function." (p.299)

Answer (score 11):

It appears that the answers to this question have changed a bit as we've progressed through the betas. As of beta 4, both the `by()` function and the `ReversedRange` type have been removed from the language. If you're looking to make a reversed range, your options are now as follows:

1: Create a forward range, and then use the `reverse()` function to reverse it.

```
for x in reverse(0 ... 4) {
    println(x) // 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
}

for x in reverse(0 ..< 4) {
    println(x) // 3, 2, 1, 0
}
```

2: Use the new `stride()` functions that were added in beta 4, which includes functions to specify the starting and ending indexes, as well as the amount to iterate by.

```
for x in stride(from: 0, through: -8, by: -2) {
    println(x) // 0, -2, -4, -6, -8
}

for x in stride(from: 6, to: -2, by: -4) {
    println(x) // 6, 2
}
```

Note that I've also included the new exclusive range operator in this post as well. `..` was replaced with `..<`.

**Edit:** From the Xcode 6 [beta 5 release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_5_za4gu6/xcode_6_beta_5_release_notes.pdf), Apple added the following suggestion for handling this:

> ReverseRange has been removed; use lazy(x..

Here's an example.

```
for i in lazy(0...5).reverse() {
    // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
}
```

Comment: +1 I'm looking for a reference to `lazy(0....5).reverse()` and I don't see the beta 5 release notes. Do you know of other discussions on this topic? Also, FYI, the numbers inside that `for` loop are backwards in your example.

Comment: @Rob Hmm I should have figured that the release notes for a beta would eventually get taken down. When I wrote this, that was the only place I had seen a reference to lazy(), but I'll gladly look around for some more and update/correct this when I get home later. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @0x7fffffff In your last example, the comment says `// 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` but it actually should be reversed. The comment is misleading.

Answer (score 6):

Xcode 7, beta 2 *(< Swift 3.0)*:

```
for i in (1...5).reverse() {
  // do something
}
```

---

**Update for Xcode 8.0+** *(Swift 3.0+)*, per [Developer Documentation, available as of 8 Dec 2020](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1690025-reversed):

- To *iterate through a collection in reverse*, without changing the collection's contents, use `reversed` -

```
let word = "Backwards"
for char in word.reversed() {
    print(char, terminator: "")
}
// Prints "sdrawkcaB"
```

In this case, a wrapper around the collection reads the collection's contents and returns them in reverse order.

- To *reverse the collection's contents*, use a type initializer, and provide it the collection `reversed`. This makes a new collection with the same contents, but reversed:

```
let reversedWord = String(word.reversed())
print(reversedWord)
// Prints "sdrawkcaB"
```

- Additionally, you can use the generic function [`stride(from:to:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641347-stride) to return the collection's contents in reverse (as well as in its normal order):

```
for countdown in stride(from: 3, to: 0, by: -1) {
    print("\(countdown)...")
}
// 3...
// 2...
// 1...
```

If the `from` value is higher than the `to` value, and the `by` value is negative, `stride` reads contents in reverse.

If the `from` value is lower than the `to` value, and the `by` value is positive, `stride` will read through the contents in their original order.

*Note:* Collections include arrays, sets, dictionaries, as well as other specialized collections. As long as the collection is iterable, these techniques will work.

*2nd Note:* as of 8 Dec 2020, Swift versions and their associated Xcode versions can be found at https://swiftly.dev/swift-versions. According to this reference, Xcode 8.0+ is associated with Swift 3.0, which is when `reverse()` became `reversed()`.

Comment: `reverse()` is now `reversed()`

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3, 4+**: you can do it like this:

```
for i in sequence(first: 10, next: {$0 - 1}) {

    guard i >= 0 else {
        break
    }
    print(i)
}
```

**result**: 10, 9, 8 ... 0

You can customise it any way you like. For more info read [`func sequence<T>` reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2015879-sequence)

Answer (score 2):

This could be another way of doing this.

```
(1...5).reversed().forEach { print($0) }
```