# operator or method in swift which work as walrus operator of python

Tags: swift, operators, new-operator, assignment-operator, walrus-operator

`walrus operator` of `python language` ( := )
work:- `assign` the value & also `return` that value.

language like swift at value assign it return nothing.
how to implement `walrus operator` kind a thing in `swift language` ?

I think it done by make function, pass address of variable & value.
assign value in that address & return value.
Is this work or any other way for this?

Comment: Do you mean like `+=` and `-=`? `var x = 2; x += 2; //x is now 4`. If not perhaps you could supply a clearer example to your question

Comment: I mention walrus operator, work as...
b = 10;
while b > 0{
    print(b := b-1)
}  
this will print 9,8....0

Comment: No I think you will need to split `print(b := b-1)` into `b -= 1; print(b)`

Comment: python also do same by splitting, but still they give this for best uses. I WAS want that by custom operator.

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom operator?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "limited symbols"

Comment: yes, I tried & get proper result. Only issue is, that have limited symbols (Not all "special characters" allow.), which we use as operators. b goes 9 to 0 is just example, I was need to use that whenever I need.

Answer (score 0):

Joakim is correct.

Swift doesn't have a unary operator like C.

In C, you could do:

```
b = 10;
while (b>0) {
   print(b--);
}
```

In Swift, there isn't a unary ++ or -- operator, so you would do:

```
var b = 10
while (b > 0) {
   print b
   b -= 1
}
```

but, really, in Swift, you'd do this instead

```
for b in (0...10).reversed() { 
   print b
}
```

See [Reverse Range in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372559/reverse-range-in-swift)

Comment: b goes 9 to 0 is just example, I was need to use that function whenever I need.